# How to get all elements that are drawn inside canvas context?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I am doing some game in canvas (game in web browser). I draw all my elements in canvas and put them into same context. Now, I need to get all element that are drawn. How I can do that?
I saw that is possible with fabric.js, but can it be done with plain js?